# sending data to the server via port 5555 C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am wanting to send some data to a server from a client application to the server via port 5555. I don't have a window's server. My question is if I purchase a .Net Framework hosting service. Would I be able to connect the client application to this server. and could I do it by sending a Post. I am new to this, so excuse me if it doesn't entire make sense. but I am looking for just some little direction. If someone could explain what port 5555 is used for that would be great.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You need a program on the server listening on your chosen port if you want to actually receive any data. What data are you wanting to send?

Comment: I do not know of any standard service that listens on 5555.  What are you trying to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom port for data exchange + tcp/ip has been identified to be very difficult across the Internet, due to firewalls/gateways everywhere.

Why not use REST web service or SOAP web service for data exchange? That has been proved to be a firewall friendly approach as it uses port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting provides will only allow incoming connections on the standard web ports (80 for unencrypted traffic/http and 443 for encrypted/https). Outgoing connections are less likely to be restricted, but it is not uncommon that only a few specific ports are open.

If you're developing a custom solution and you do not need a connection that allows you to continually send data back and forth, then a hosted solution will do fine. If you do need the live link or custom port numbers then you'll need to upgrade to a virtual managed server, which is essentially your own virtual copy of a Windows server. This costs more but allows you to listen on custom ports - essentially do as you please.

As for determining the specific use of a port, most networked applications have simply picked one or more numbers without much research. [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) maintains a list of protocols/applications/services and their associated port numbers, but being listed requires that an application is sent and approved.